# Why does eip doesn't change in this buffer overflow attempt?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, cpu-registers, buffer-overflow

Im trying to play with buffer overflows. I don't understand what's going on here with the value of eip.

Here is the C code :

```
void copy(char *arg) {
  char msg[256];
  strcpy(msg,arg);
}
```

The assembly for it :

```
0x804847d <copy+25>:    call   0x8048368 <strcpy@plt>
0x8048482 <copy+30>:    leave  
0x8048483 <copy+31>:    ret
```

I input as an argument a string like "***_***\xAA\xBB\xCC\xDD" with a size calculated so that the last 4 bytes will be 4 bytes after $ebp (in order to overwrite the real return address). And it seems to work.

in gdb:

```
(break before strcpy)
x/2wx $ebp
0xbffffb38: 0xbffffb58  0x080484d2
n
(just after strcpy execution)
x/2wx $ebp
0xbffffb38: 0x80cdd189  0x080484b6
...
n
...
x/2wx $ebp
0xbffffb38: 0x80cdd189  0x080484b6
```

So the return address was `0x080484d2` and after my overflow it is `0x080484b6`, which is what I want. but the program exits : "Cannot access memory at address 0x80cdd18d".

I don't know why $eip was not set to my address, and because of the address of the code in 0x08048... I am pretty confident that $ebp+4 was the place containing the return address

I tried again with a string 4 bytes smaller and this time it overwrote $ebp and not $ebp+4 and after the return the $eip was set to the value contained in $ebp+4

Any explanations ?

Comment: Maybe the attempt to access 0x80cdd18d was a result of running the instruction(s) at 0x80484b6. How do you know it *didn't* jump there?

Comment: I kept doing "next" on gdb and it went to 0x80cdd18d without passing through 0x80484b6

Comment: The "Cannot access memory" message doesn't mean your program's %eip went there. It doesn't even mean your program tried to access the address! It means **gdb** wanted to access that address in the inferior process's address space for some reason and couldn't. It's common to see that kind of warning during a gdb session of a program that is misbehaving. And yours is certainly misbehaving - it has a buffer overflow! Try using `stepi` instead of `next` to single-step instructions after the strcpy, and you might get a clearer idea what's going on.

Comment: You might find it useful to `display/i $pc` (and maybe some other interesting registers) and `stepi` through the return sequence.

Comment: Thanks to your comments, I posted an answer, the problem was that the value at $ebp was changed during the overwriting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so thanks @Wumpus Q. Wumbley, this helped me understand things.

Doing `next` jumps `leave` and `ret` altogether. `ret` is the instruction that changes `eip`, it must be equivalent of `pop eip`. But `leave` modifies the stack pointers `esp` and `ebp` before (especially because when I am overwriting ebp+4 I change the value contained at ebp)

TLDR : Not overwriting the value at ebp makes it work successfully.

Comment: `next` doesn't jump the `leave` and `ret` (in the sense of not executing them). It just doesn't return to the gdb prompt after each instruction. Its purpose is to continue until the current *source* line is done. Sometimes that takes a few instructions, sometimes a lot. `next`, `step`, `nexti`, and `stepi` all have their uses but `stepi` is the most useful one in this case since it doesn't care about source lines. When you're doing buffer overflow exploits, the state of the running process diverges sharply from what is expressed in the source-level debugging information. `next` gets confused.

Comment: so this explains half of the problem but it doesn't say why it didn't work in the first place

`leave` then `ret` makes ebp point to the old ebp and esp point to ebp (+- some bytes) and eip to the value in ebp+4. So when overwriting the value in ebp, everything will be ok except the "old ebp" that will become wrong. But esp and eip will be good, so why doesn't it work ?

Comment: The corrupted "old %ebp" will be loaded into the real %ebp register by the `leave` instruction. Then your `ret` takes you to the address you chose in your exploit. Whatever is at that address will have problems if it requires a usable %ebp

Comment: Ok, the problem is just before 'ret'. When I do step in (to execute ret) it says "cannot access memory at address ...". So it didn't have time to pop eip, it (gdb or the processor ?) just did some sort of check to see if ebp is a valid stack pointer and it is not.

Comment: `gdb` likes to print some information about the current stack frame every time the program stops. When you have no valid stack frame as a result of a buffer overflow, that's likely to cause some warnings. You just have to learn to ignore them and print what you need by hand.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for x86 (as opposed to x86-64), the usual function prologue involves pushing `ebp` and then assigning it the value of `esp`, which would leave the return address on the stack at `ebp+4`.

Take a look at a disassembly of your function, and see if the first instructions look like this:

```
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp
```

If so, this is the cause of the offset.

Comment: yes, this is x86 and the first instructions look like what you say. So now that it is confirmed that ebp+4 should contain the RA, why doesn't it work ?

Comment: It seems as if you are controlling the value of `eip` successfully, and something else is going wrong. Hard to say what without more info.